# Schröder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand that I must show injection between two sets in order to use the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem, but I am having a hard time constructing them.

For example, if I want to show that [0,1] and [0,5] have the same cardinality, how do I go about showing that the two are one-to-one?

Comment: An explicit bijection is $x \mapsto 5x$.

Answer (score 0):

Schöder-Bernstein theorem say that if exist injections for both sides, exist a bijection.

In your example, is easy show a bijection: $x\to5x$.

Answer (score 0):

The point of Schroeder-Bernstein is that you do not have to construct an explicit bijection, it shows that there is one.  You just need to find an injection each direction.  If you want, you can chase through the construction to try to find the bijection.  As Crostul says, you can make an explicit bijection in this case by $x \mapsto 5x$, but you can also find an injection $x \in [0,1] \mapsto x \in [0,5]$ and another $x \in [0,5] \mapsto \frac x{10} \in [0,1]$.  You can then invoke Schroeder-Bernstein to say there is a bijection.  The bijection will use one of the maps for some intervals and the other for other intervals, but you don't care.